Standard for setting max width for a body of text
Let's say I have a body of text on my website for users using my website on mobile. Is the industry standard for the max-width to be a maximum of 90vw or 95vw? Why would one be better than the other?

Where did you get this industry standard?

@Luciano chatGPT

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125770/does-the-980px-screen-width-rule-still-stand https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/how-can-i-determine-how-large-of-a-font-size-and-how-wide-of-a-container-to-use

I am not aware of a "industry standard" for max-width on mobile. There might be reasons for visual appeal to choose either value. Depends on the use-case.
